# Choosing Outliers using Chauvenet's Criterion

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, outliers

I have normal data and have applied Chauvenet's Criterion to all my data points to determine if there were any outliers that must be removed. I have 2 groups of subjects, male and female, and when I input all of these values (from both male and female groups), I get one data point from the female group that is an outlier. However, if I test just the female values, then this one point is not considered an outlier.

How am I supposed to apply this to my data, I cannot tell whether or not to remove this data point. There is no statistical significance between the male and female groups, but the female group seems to have greater variation.

I will be running an ANOVA with this dataset.

Comment: This is a poor approach, because the computation of the mean and SD needed to apply it can be thoroughly distorted by the presence of the outlier.  It sounds like what you really need might be advice on whether and how to detect outliers in your situation.  But to provide that, we will need you to describe your data and explain your objectives.

Comment: If the so-called outliers are not erroneous measurements, removing them would remove valid information and bias the analysis. It is not good practice to remove outliers detected by any data based criterion without trying to find out what caused an observation to be outlying, and whether it carries valid information or not.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your input, I have 2 groups of animals (ages 1-3 and ages 9+) with almost equal amounts of males and females in each group (more males than females (n16 vs n15)). I am looking at a gut health measurement for each animal and my main question is to check if the measurement changes with age (or sex, but seemingly does not). This one animal who has a high output value is part of the older group, so ideally I would use her data to prove that yes, the outcome changes with age. Running the statistics with and without her data point shows that it does increase with age anyways.

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thank you! That makes sense, I will look further into this specific animal's health history to check if there could be another reason it is so high

Comment: That's a reasoned approach.  It suggests you have already dodged the question of whether to remove the point: it sounds like it doesn't matter.